# How to save and recreate android activities

Tags: android

I'm trying to teach myself some android programming and I'm unable to get my app to save and load a users progress.

Currently I initialise my variables level and score in my activity. Then call this from my onCreate method:

```
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        playersScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        level = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        playersScore = 0;
        level = 0;
    }
```

and finally I have a method for saving a bundle:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, playersScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, level);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

For some reason my bundle wont save, any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> Note that it is important to save persistent data in onPause() instead of onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) because the latter is not part of the lifecycle callbacks, so will not be called in every situation as described in its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    playersScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
    level = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
}
```

Also shouldn't:

```
savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, playersScore);
savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, level);
```

be:

```
savedInstanceState.putInt("STATE_SCORE", playersScore);
savedInstanceState.putInt("STATE_LEVEL", level);
```

As putInt() requires a string and an int.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that I initialised STATE_SCORE and STATE_LEVEL as Strings. I managed to get it working using persistent data, saved in onPause(). Thanks for the help though